# how can i print the component's id of Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

there are a link of  official document :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component

Here’s a complete example of a simple todo list:

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '\
    <li>\
      {{ title }}\
      <button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button>\
    </li>\
  ',
  props: ['title']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#todo-list-example',
  data: {
    newTodoText: '',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Do the dishes',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Take out the trash',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Mow the lawn'
      }
    ],
    nextTodoId: 4
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTodo: function () {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.nextTodoId++,
        title: this.newTodoText
      })
      this.newTodoText = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="todo-list-example">
  <input
    v-model="newTodoText"
    v-on:keyup.enter="addNewTodo"
    placeholder="Add a todo"
  >
  <ul>
    <li
      is="todo-item"
      v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
      v-bind:key="todo.id"
      v-bind:title="todo.title"
      v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"
    ></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**results:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJDGc.png)

---

i try to print todo.id . for example:

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
      template: '\
        <li>\
          {{ id }}-{{ title }}\
          <button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button>\
        </li>\
      ',
      props: ['id','title']
    })
```

but the result is the same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1fvO.png)
so, how should i print the todo.id?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/93626/#fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to actually provide the `id` to the `<li is="todo-item" ... >`s, which isn't being done. You need to add `v-bind:id="todo.id"`.

That being said, if you're trying to print it from any of [the Vue instance lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), then it's as easy as `console.log(this.id)`. For example:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  ...
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.id)
  }
}
```

P.S. don't use jQuery! Using jQuery with Vue is a code-smell. [Here's a pretty informational rant by Gitlab on why that is (plus more).](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/09/gitlab-vue-one-year-later/)